# Passing anonymous object of derived class to a routine in Eiffel

Tags: constructor, eiffel, anonymous-objects

Assuming that we have:

```
class A ...
class B inherit A ...

f (a_a: A) ...
```

Then, can you write something like the following pseudocode, without using a temporary variable?

```
-- `y` is an argument to B's constructor.
f (create B.make(y))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for a creation expression. Unlike creation instruction, it omits target entity, but always specifies a creation type:

```
create {B}.make (y)
```

*Note.* As a rule of thumb, if a type can be confused with an entity, it is enclosed in curly braces. For example, in the phrase `create B.make (y)` the terminal `B` is interpreted as an entity name. Enclosing it in the braces promotes it to a type.